# UML state diagram definition

Tags: uml, state-diagram

In a state machine diagram,  actions can be executed within states and also during transitions?

This definition is true or false?

Answer (score 1):

yes, replacing 'actions' by 'behavior' to be more precise (and in a state machine, 'diagram' is not relevant here)

from [formal/2017-12-05](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/) §*14.2.3.4.3 State entry, exit, and doActivity Behaviors* :

> A State may have an associated entry Behavior. This Behavior, if defined, is executed whenever the State is entered
> through an external Transition. In addition, a State may also have an associated exit Behavior, which, if defined, is
> executed whenever the State is exited.
>
> A State may also have an associated doActivity Behavior. This Behavior commences execution when the State is entered
> (but only after the State entry Behavior has completed) and executes concurrently with any other Behaviors that may be
> associated with the State, until:
>
> - it completes (in which case a completion event is generated) or
> - the State is exited, in which case execution of the doActivity Behavior is aborted.
>
> The execution of a doActivity Behavior of a State is not affected by the firing of an internal Transition of that State.

and from [formal/2017-12-05](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/) § *14.2.3.8 Transitions* :

> A Transition ... It may have an
> associated effect Behavior, which is executed when the Transition is traversed (executed).

A *Behavior* can be an *OpaqueBehavior, Activity, StateMachine*, or *Interaction* (see [formal/2017-12-05](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/) § *13.4.2.4 Specializations* concerning the abstract class *Behavior*)